# How do I configure .vue files import from .ts file in vim?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, neovim, language-server-protocol

I have encountered a problem trying to configure NeoVim to work with Vue. On a freshly installed LunarVim instance I'm trying to work with .ts files, but there is an error with importing .vue file. My treesitter has configuration for vue and typescript. Also tsserver and volar LSPs work just fine. There is autocompletion and everything. But in imports there are errors: `Cannot find module './App.vue' or its corresponding type declarations`. And yes, I'm sure that there is App.vue file, the problem is only with .vue files.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJMbJ.png)

I've tried reinstalling tsserver and volar, but it didn't help.